# I erased my whole project setting up my git repo. Is there anything I can do?

Tags: git, repository, bitbucket

I opened up Time Machine, but it turns out I don't have it setup. So that option is out.

I open up my Trash, and it's not in there. So that option is out.

Here's what I did.

I have an existing repo on bitbucket. It's from long ago.

I recently started another project, and decided I would put it on bitbucket as well.

I was in bitbucket, and by mistake attempted to follow the "I have an existing project" instead of "I'm starting from scratch".

So I never init'd a new git repo. I went to my project directory and did the following...

```
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:myusername/myproject.git
git push - u origin --all

No refs in common and none specific: doing nothing
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as master
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly 
Everything up to date

git status

At this point I noticed not just my intended project were staged, but a bunch of other examples, demos, and projects were. Then there were a bunch of files not staged, and a bunch of untracked files.

git add -A
git status

At this point, just about everything was staged. Whoops. What the heck am I doing.

ls -al

I beginning look for the .git file realizing now I never created it, as I followed the wrong steps on bitbucket.

git reset --hard

I decide to just reset everything, in a lapse of judgement.
```

Now everything is gone. No files in Trash, no option for Time Machine. Nothing on bitbucket obviously.

What options do I have? Start over from scratch? Why isn't there anything in my Trash?

Comment: You need to create a repository by calling ´´git init´´. Looks like your stuff is gone, shouldn't have used reset --hard. Check your bitbucket repo, if you didn't pushed anything.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you checked out your old repo, and then in it's folder created your new project?

Comment: I think you are missing some steps, it is not possible to perform any git commands on a non-repository folder. Any command will return `fatal: Not a git repository`. Since you was able to run git commands, you should have `.git` folder in the project folder. Check if it is still there, try to run `git log` to check the revision history or `gitk` to browse it visually (gitk is usually installed with git, not sure about Mac OS, you may try some other [git gui](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis)). If there is nothing in history, then most probably your files are lost.

Comment: And if files are lost you may try to restore them with some low-level utilites, there should be tools to scan the HD and search for deleted files (again, can't advice something specific for Mac). They may work or not, that depends on luck.

Answer (score 0):

Is your old repo not still on bitbucket?  I assume as you didn't manage to push anything to bitbucket that the files you erased were your local copy of your bitbucket repo.  If so then you should be able to clone your repo from bitbucket again.

Regarding trash, things are only put in trash when using Finder, files deleted by applications and directly using rm will always just be unlinked from the file system and not appear in trash.  If this were not the case then your Trash can would be full of temporary files created by your OS and applications as they operate.

Hope you are able to recover your work.

Comment: Yeah J have my old repo but the problem is, because I was trying to create a new repo for my new project, I never pushed these projects changes up to my old repo. Did a reset hard instead.

Comment: In that case I believe you will have wiped out all your local changes.  unless you have a local backup it sounds to me like they will be gone :( sorry.  My personal advice would be to take a copy of the whole directory before making significant changes with VCS, has saved me a few times now.  No use to you now, but hopefully will be for future.

Answer (score 0):

The repository must have been initialized if you were able to run git commands in the folder.

Are there any commits in the reflog that you can checkout?:

```
git reflog
```

If you see a state that you would like to revert to copy the hash and check it out:

```
git checkout c49b4a7
```

Hope this helps!